How to access files on phone from command line Gnome 42.9 Ubuntu 22.04
This gvfs thing is giving me problems, and the gvfs documentation is little help.  There doesn't seem to be a way to access my Moto one 5G ace, except at gnome/gvfs/nautilitis
I can plug in USB drives and find them in /.../media.  What I can't find is my USB phone outside of Gnome and its file manager (Nautilus?).  And the file manager is most difficult. For example, viewing the files in another user's /home folder. So, if I could only find the phone using the file selector in programs that can drill down from the root directory!
My Gnome desktop has icons for SSDs, USB storage plug-ins AND an icon for my phone.  Opening it starts the file manger, which is a problem (see above).  I can't seem to find the name of the phone.  It's not in the file manager properties, it's not in /dev or /.../media (unlike all the other USB devices).  I can't figure out a gvfs command to show it.
Since I can't find the device outside the file manager, I can't create a symlink. Nobody seems able to find it to mount it.
When my favorite compare program or file manager or viewer asks for a name that will reach some file on the phone, what do I enter?

MTP-mounted devices should be listed under /run/user/$UID/gvfs/, where UID is your user id (usually 1000 on single-user systems), does this help?

And if it doesn't, open the root of the mounted filesystem for your phone from Nautilus, then right-click somewhere empty and click "Open in terminal" -> then run pwd in the terminal to see the full path.

Thank you. /run/users/..... locates the device.  So far, all the legacy programs seems to be able to access them using this location. {There must be several long term projects that won't agree on where to keep things.}
